# make bindings work without running application

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.5

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="260">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="23" x:Name="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

```cs
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var win = new MainWindow();
        var vm = new ViewModel();
        win.DataContext = vm;
        vm.Test = "Testing";

        //var app = new Application();
        //app.Run(win);

        var text = win.TextBox.Text;
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public string Test { get; set; }
    }
```

If I run the application as is, the value of the variable `text` will be an empty string. If I uncomment the two lines that run the window as a WPF application, it will be "Testing", which means the TextBox's binding to the property `Test` on class `ViewModel` works only if I 'run' the application.

Is there any way to make that binding work without actually running the application?

Comment: @BenRobinson I would like to make unit tests for my WPF application, but if possible i would like to abstain from actually running any visual part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you manually set a binding on a `DependencyObject` (using `BindingOperations.SetBinding`) with the `Source` specified, the binding works fine, even if the application is not running.

So in this case, I think the problem is that the  `Window` hasn't been loaded yet, so the visual tree is not ready, so `DataContext` propagation doesn't work, so the binding doesn't have a source.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to do this:

```
    var win = new MainWindow();
    var vm = new ViewModel(); // Remove this line
    win.DataContext = vm;  // Remove this line
    vm.Test = "Testing";  // Remove this line
```

In your XAML, change this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourViewModelNameSpace"  // Add this, change to correct namespace
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="260">
<Window.DataContext> // Add this tag and contents
    <local:ViewModel/> // This instantiates the ViewModel class and assigns it to DataContext
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Height="23" x:Name="TextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
```

And your class:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()  // Add this constructor
    {
        Test = "Testing";
    }

    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

In the XAML probably you have to remove the explaining comments.

This is how I get it:
[image]

Comment: @Thomas `..without actually running the application?` As I understood it, there is no need to show the window; that has to be done at runtime. So I did a suggestion to show the `Testing` label at designtime (then the bindings work as well).